# Python Locust load testing how to upload and submit xml file

Tags: python-3.x, flask, locust

I am trying to figure out how many concurrent users can upload xml files using Locust

locust file

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class HttpSession(TaskSet):
        @task
        def post_img(self):
            headers = {'1': '1', '2': '2'}
            test_file = 'c:\\xmlfolder\a.xml'
            url='/uploadxml'
            self.client.request('POST', '/upload', files={'file': open(test_file, 'rb')}, headers=headers)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    host = 'http://localhost:5000'
    task_set = HttpSession
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 3000
```

When I run my locust file I get a 405 error

Ideally I want to give it atleast 3 or more xml files and spin up three /upload sessions and then upload 3 different xml files what am I doing wrong ?

this is a flask app which is already passed functional testing using selenium
os =windows and hence the slashes

Comment: Where is the 405 coming from? That's a serverside error no one knows why is happening.

Comment: I am running a localhost:5000 flask server(if you can call it that) and this is what I get in the flask window 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2018 11:13:24] "POST /uploadxml HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `files` argument isn't working as you (or I) expect it to.

I copied your code and looked at what was being received by a Django app. The data had the filename prepended to the XML data. I changed the locust task to load the data into a variable and passed the data to the request:

```
class HttpSession(TaskSet):
    @task
    def post_img(self):                
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/xml'}
        with open('request_data.xml', 'r') as xml_fh:
            xml_data = xml_fh.read()
        self.client.request(
            method='POST',
            url='/upload',
            data=xml_data,
            headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The acceptance answer is fine, but the path to the file was not working for me, so on top of it, I had to add:

```
import os
```

and then

```
...
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'request_data.xml')
with open('request_data.xml', 'r') as xml_fh:
           xml_data = xml_fh.read()
...
```